# Exceptions in send_mail when fail_silently=True

Tags: django, django-email

I was going to use send_mail function to send email, and I was hoping that using `fail_silently=True` would prevent this function from raising exceptions.

It turns out it does work if `SMTPException` is raised; however I noticed it doesn't intercept `socket.error exception` - so if STMP server is down, an exception will be raised even with `fail_silently=True`

I'm now wondering how to get the complete list of exceptions raised by `send_mail` so I can catch them in try/except loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are unsure about which exceptions to catch, then simply catch `Exception`

Comment: @ruddra I didn't want to do it initially because I thought PyCharm will give "Too broad exception cause" warning if I do that. But if I do `except Exception as e:` it seems to be perfectly valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that catch an `Exception` is a very final approach. Since both `SMTPException` and `socket.error` are children of `IOError` you can catch an `IOError` instead. If you'll ever catch something else - you can add this to your catch list later.